# How to search for the form which is stored in local storage in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, html

I have a objects in which i am storing it into the local storage.If i want to store another object ,before it is saved i want to check wheather the object is already existed in the localstorage .If existed if u want to replace it or add it with another name .
I need to do this ..I am unable to identify how to search if number of objects are already stored in the local storage.Can anyone please solve this problem.

```
localStorage.setItem( $scope.form.Name, angular.toJson($scope.form));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can't search in the local storage - you have to get the value from the storage and search it yourself, as you would with a file for example.

But you could use a [web database] (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_web_sql.htm) (also HTML5 feature) which allows you to store and find object in a DB.

Answer (score 0):

use `localStorage.get("prop")` to verify if the name is already taken and the value exists (then you can compare values), if it's not you will get an `undefined`, so you can run this test

```
if (localStorage.get("prop")) {
    // do something to prop because it exists 
}
```

get length of localStorage by using the build-in `length` property, like

```
console.log(localStorage.length);
// will print 42 or something..
```

if you want to see what's inside localStorage, remember that it's an JS object like everything else so you can iterate it's properties using a `for .. in` loop

```
for (var prop in localStorage) {
    console.log(localStorage[prop]);
}
```